# How to type double braces and parentheses inside quotes in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Every time when I type something inside quotes in Pycharm I only get one brace or parenthesis and Pycharm doesn't complete it with the second one. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Yeah. You type the other parentheses.

Comment: What version of Pycharm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Do what @Batman suggested on the comments. (recommended)
2. Type without quotes, then add quotes after.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings for pairs of brackets, quotes, and braces.  If that doesn't solve your problem, you might be seeing a bug.  [image]